# Accessing a child input element through its parent's ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using es6.

I have a a parent and two child components.
The first child component(UploadForm) holds an input tag which is used to upload files to the server.
The parent component needs to know which are those files (how many of them and their names), compute the total files size and send the result back to the second child component(Status) along with some other props.

Now all I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refs' of undefined`, from my parent component. 
What am I doing wrong?

This is my parent component

```
import './App.scss';
import React,
{
  Component,
  PropTypes
}                     from 'react';
import ReactDOM       from 'react-dom';
import UploadForm     from 'elements/uploadForm';
import { Status }     from 'elements/status';

class AppLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getUploadedFiles = () => {
    return this.refs.form.refs.uploadInput.files;
  }

  getUploadedFilesSize = () => {
    let sizeTotal = this.props.filesSize,
        files_a = this.getUploadedFiles,
        files_cnt = files_a.length;

    for (let indx = 0; indx < files_cnt; indx++) {
      sizeTotal += files_a[indx].size;
    }

    let size_cnt = sizeTotal + " bytes";

    for (let  sizeExtensions = ["KB","MB","GB","TB","PB","EB","ZB","YB"],
                indx = 0, 
                approx = sizeTotal / 1024; 
              approx > 1; 
              approx /= 1024, indx++
        ) { 
      size_cnt = approx.toFixed(3) + " " + sizeExtensions[indx];
    }
    return size_cnt;
  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <div id="appWrapper">

        <UploadForm ref="form" updateSize={this.getUploadedFilesSize()} >
          <Status filesNum={this.getUploadedFiles().length} 
                  filesSize={this.getUploadedFilesSize()} 
          />
        </UploadForm>

      </div>  
    )
  }
}

AppLayout.propTypes = {
  filesNum:   PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  filesSize:  PropTypes.number.isRequired
}

AppLayout.defaultProps = {
  filesNum: 0,
  filesSize: 0
}

export default AppLayout;
```

And this is my child component(UploadForm):

```
import React, 
{
  PropTypes,
  Component
}                         from 'react';

class UploadForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        filesNum:   this.props.filesNum,
        filesSize:  this.props.filesSize
      })
    );

    return (
      <div>
      <form name="uploadForm">
        <input id="uploadInput" 
               type="file" 
               name="myFiles" 
               onChange={this.props.updateSize}
               multiple
               ref="uploadInput"
        /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Send file" />

      </form>
        {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default UploadForm;
```

So basically, `<UploadForm>` gets its props from the parent component. Then, it passes those props down to its own child component, `<Status>`.

But the parent component needs to get the uploaded files from the `<UploadForm>` component before passing those 2 props to it: `filesNum` and `filesSize`.

I am confused as to how to operate that, considering the error I get.

The parent component fetches the `filesNum` data from the input element within `<UploadForm>` to get the files uploaded by the user and renders its own child component

Comment: i'm not seeing the uploadInput ref anywhere....log out this.refs.form and see what you can access inside of it

Comment: My bad, I pasted an earlier version of the component. I now have made the change in the question. Sorry.

Comment: console.log(this.refs.form) is undefined

Comment: Hmmm that's odd...I was using refs the other day and I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary...

Comment: The problem must be with the <Status> component since when I delete it from the the parent component, I can get data from console.log(this.refs.form)

Comment: Is there a reason you have Status as a child of UploadForm but in the parent component and not in the UploadForm component?

Comment: UI. I need to render the Status in its own sticky div at the bottom of the page rather than within the <UploadForm> component.

Comment: Can't you just do that with CSS?

Comment: try console.log(this.refs["form"])